# Want a result for a calculator screen to show '2+4-3' in another label

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I want to create 2 labels for a calculator . Calculatorscreen which shows the calculations and the Resultscreen which shows what type of operations are being performed . How should I do it ? Here are my methods :-

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
 { 
  currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + (float)[sender tag];
  calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",currentNumber];
 }

-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender
{

}
```

Where do I append the operators into the label with the numerals to show a complete set of operations ?

Comment: Hello there. Looking at your questions so far, it looks like you're trying to build a calculator, and struggling with every step. If so, I _strongly_ reccommend the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U. It's a great beginners resource, and the first project is to build a calculator!

Comment: Those videos will get you going.